# How to solve conflict between react-router-dom v6 and mobx?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, mobx

I've created dynamic routing on my site, which changes when a user login successfully. The fact of logging I keep in global state, which observers by mobx. When the user login successfully, routes changes too, and it works correctly, but in the console, there is the next problem:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g985a.png)

Error in text variant:

react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by AppRouter. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

### Previous render            Next render

1. useState                   useState
2. useState                   useState
3. useRef                     useRef
4. useDebugValue              useDebugValue
5. useEffect                  useEffect
6. useContext                 useContext
7. undefined                  useContext
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

There is a screenshot of the route's component:
[Routes component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpq2e.png)
Routes component code:

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Context } from "../..";
import { adminPaths, guestPaths, userPaths } from "./paths";
const AppRouter = () => {
  const { userStore } = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/*' element={<Navigate to='/' />} />
      {
        userStore.isAuth && userPaths.map(({ path, component }) => 
          <Route path={path} element={component()} />)
      }
      {
        userStore.isAuth && adminPaths.map(({ path, component }) => 
          <Route path={path} element={component()} />)
      }
      {
        guestPaths.map(({ path, component }) => <Route path={path} element={component()} />)
      }
    </Routes>
 )
}
export default observer(AppRouter);
```

When I remove the observer in this component, error disappeared, but routes don't update after login.

Routes configuration code:
[Routes configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEVVd.png)
Routes configuration code:

```
import AdminCabinet from "../../pages/admin-cabinet/admin-cabinet";
import HomePage from "../../pages/home-page/home-page";
import UserCabinet from "../../pages/user-cabinet/user-cabinet";

export const guestPaths = [
    {
        name: 'Home',
        path: '/',
        component: HomePage
    }
];
export const userPaths = [
    {
        name: 'Personal cabinet',
        path: '/personalCabinet',
        component: UserCabinet
    }
];
export const adminPaths = [
    {
        name: 'Admin cabinet',
        path: '/adminCabinet',
        component: AdminCabinet
    }
];
```

I would be grateful if someone helps me with this problem.

Comment: Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you are trying to work with. Can you include the routes configuration that you are mapping? The `element={component()}` seems a little suspect to me.

Comment: Routes configuration code screenshot added.

Comment: Please, include *actual* code and error messages as properly formatted code snippets and quoted text, not as images. Images are not searchable or copy/paste-able, and can be more difficult to read.

Comment: Code in text format added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The only overt issue I see with your code is that you are directly invoking your React components instead of rendering them as JSX for React to handle and manage the component lifecycle of.

Example:

```
import UserCabinet from "../../pages/user-cabinet/user-cabinet";

const userPaths = [
  {
    name: "Personal cabinet",
    path: "/personalCabinet",
    component: UserCabinet,
  },
];
```

...

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  const { userStore } = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <Routes>
      ...
      {userStore.isAuth && userPaths.map(({ path, component }) => (
        <Route path={path} element={component()} /> // <-- invoking component
      ))}
      ...
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

## Solution

The `element` prop should receive JSX. When destructuring `component` rename it to `Component` so it has a valid React component name and render as JSX. Don't forget to use a valid React key for the mapped routes.

Example:

```
import UserCabinet from "../../pages/user-cabinet/user-cabinet";

const userPaths = [
  {
    name: "Personal cabinet",
    path: "/personalCabinet",
    component: UserCabinet,
  },
];
```

...

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  const { userStore } = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <Routes>
      ...
      {userStore.isAuth && userPaths.map(({ path, component: Component }) => (
        <Route
          key={path}
          path={path}
          element={<Component />} // <-- pass as JSX
        />
      ))}
      ...
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yep, it helped me, thanks a lot, but to be honest I don't really understand why this error happens.

Comment: @Андрей In React you don't ever directly call your React components. You effectively pass a reference to them as JSX, and React handles "converting" them to vanilla JS functions and manages calling them when it is rendering the UI. [JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) may help explain better than I have. JSX is syntactic sugar for `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)`. When you call directly the component, React isn't managing any of the lifecycle nor hook calls.